# List of cardViews is not updated Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am working on an Android project where I need to create two activities with one list of cardViews for each: `ListServices.Java` and `HomePage.java`

I want that if I click on a cardview in ListServices, I get redirected back to HomePage and the same cardView should be created/added to HomePage list of cardViews.
 In my logs I can see the cardView added in the list in HomePage.java, but it is not displayed as a card on the view.

Here's what I have done so far:

**homePage:**

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public static ServicesAdapter homeAdapter;
public static List<Service> serviceList;
final static String ADD_NEW_ITEM_TYPE="add new item";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //cards
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    serviceList = new ArrayList<>();
    homeAdapter = new ServicesAdapter(this, serviceList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);
    initServices();
}
 public void initServices () {
    Service a = new Service(ADD_NEW_ITEM_TYPE);
    serviceList.add(a);

    homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and this activity's adapter:

```
public class ServicesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServicesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Service> serviceList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //click on new item homepage
                if(title.getText().toString().equals(ADD_NEW_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                    Intent redirect = new Intent(v.getContext(), ListServices.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(redirect);
                }
            }
        });//end onclick listener
    }

}


public ServicesAdapter(Context mContext, List<Service> serviceList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.serviceList = serviceList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.service_card, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Service serv = serviceList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(serv.getName());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return serviceList.size();
}
}
```

**ListServices:**

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ServiceListAdapter adapter;
private List<Service> servicesArray;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste_services);
//cards
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    servicesArray = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ServiceListAdapter(this, servicesArray);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HomePageServices.GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    prepareServices();
}
 private void prepareServices() {

    Service  a = new Service("Indoor Geolocation");
    servicesArray.add(a);

    a = new Service("Restauration du cartier");
    servicesArray.add(a);

    a = new Service("Signaler a dysfonctionnement");
    servicesArray.add(a);

    a = new Service("Boite à idée");
    servicesArray.add(a);

    a = new Service("Activités inter-employés");
    servicesArray.add(a);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and it's adapter:

```
public class ServiceListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServiceListAdapter.MyHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Service> servicesArray;

public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;

    public MyHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //disable card

                //redirect to homepage
                Intent redirect = new Intent(v.getContext(), HomePageServices.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(redirect);
                //create new card view
                Service s=new Service(title.getText().toString());
                serviceList.add(s);

                homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for (int i =0; i<serviceList.size(); i++){
                    Log.d("serviceLoist", serviceList.get(i).toString());

                }

            }
        });//end onclick listener





    }


}


public ServiceListAdapter(Context mContext, List<Service> serviceList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.servicesArray = serviceList;
}

@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.service_card, parent, false);

    return new MyHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, int position) {
    Service serv = servicesArray.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(serv.getName());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return servicesArray.size();
}

}
```

So as you can see the problem is here:

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //disable card

                //redirect to homepage
                Intent redirect = new Intent(v.getContext(), HomePageServices.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(redirect);
                //create new card view
                Service s=new Service(title.getText().toString());
                serviceList.add(s);

                homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thank you

Comment: you should set your adapter after data initialization. change these two line order `recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);
    initServices();` to `initServices(); recyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);`

Comment: didn't change anything

Comment: and this also. `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    prepareServices();` you should set adapter after data initialization in all places

Comment: Still doesnt work though :/

Comment: please edit question with full code by declaring .xml layouts and imports used in .java files too, its become easy to those who try to help you.